# Should spam be edited out as well as flagged?

Tags: discussion, spam

Today, somebody posted [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/342398/91730):

> afterclap means an unexpected, usually unwanted, repercussion of or sequel to an affair which had been thought to be closed from collins dictionary. Don't forget to check out *{website link that I won't repeat here because it shouldn't be preserved}*.

I initially edited out the website, because I thought that it was *irrelevant*, but that there was a genuine attempt to answer the question (although with a VLQ answer). I then realised that the username partially matched the website link, so used a custom flag to say "maybe this is spam".

My edit was then rolled back, with a comment from curiousdannii saying:

> @AndyT Don't edit out spam. It needs to remain so that other people will see it and flag it.

This was news to me. I'd have thought hiding the spam was more important, and that a mod would see the flag and delete it soon enough.

Should spam be edited out as well as flagged? Or flagged and left so that others can see and flag it?

Comment: [Here's one mod in the past saying not to edit](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4450/dealing-with-spam?rq=1#comment16017_4751). I'm not certain that is the current best practice, so lets see what they say here.

Comment: @sumelic - Cheers for finding the dupe. I did try searching for one!

Comment: @curiousdannii - Ta for link. Coupled with sumelic's dupe, I'm happy that it's best practice not to edit.

Comment: waiwai933's [linked message](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4450/142322) deserves an FAQ tag.